# Entering the password in cmd on Windows Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, passwords

I'm trying to run runas command in Windows but it asks about password. I use `system('runas /user:username cmd')` but it needs entering the password manually. Is there any possibility to enter automatically this password in my ruby script? Saving password in any file is forbidden.

--edit: ReggieB suggested to add some more information.

I'm writing a fact for Puppet. We have puppet agents installed on local Administrator accounts and local Administrator can't have access to information about domain users. Because of this I decided to run cmd as domain user that can have access to domain users. The problem is that runas command needs to manually enter the password. It's impossible to do this in facts so I need some method in Ruby that will do this automatically. I need to do

`system('runas /user:username cmd')`
and some method that enter the password in command prompt instead of me.

Comment: You want to run it as the connected windows user, or another one?

Comment: User is not connected to server.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more? What I meant to ask is if the current user is connected to a windows machine with his credentials, and you want to run something on his behalf (or log in somewhere else)?

Comment: I'm logged on as local Administrator and I want to run cmd as another (domain) user. I need to do this because local Administrator has no acces to domain controller and he can't displays information about domain users e.g. net user username /DOMAIN

Comment: How about entering the password once, and then cache the password encrypted in memory for the next times? You don't really have a lot of options since you'll actually need the password.

Comment: Oh, if it's for getting `net user` I guess it's a script that you'll run every time, so the caching I suggested won't be helpful

Comment: The task scheduler can store the user credentials, so you can create a task that will run that thing for you, and create a script or shortcut to launch that task

Comment: That is right, caching password is not helpul, I've considered it alredy. The script will be run on about hundred servers.

Comment: It's the same user for all of the servers?

Comment: The problem is that this is a fact for Puppet so I it no possible to use task scheduller.
Yes, this is technical account, the same for all servers.

Comment: How about storing the password in puppet (I believe it's via Hiera) and requesting it from the code? also not an option?

Comment: And I will able to use it writing fact? How to do this?

Comment: Can't help you with that since I'm not that familiar with ruby nor puppet. But I suggest you update the question with all the information we just had here, so that if someone does know it well - they could understand your needs from the question.